# How to respond to the claims says that Jesus went to India?

Tags: life-of-jesus, historical-jesus, christianity-in-india

I recently saw that some say Jesus went to India/Tibet in the silent ages(generally refers to the period of Jesus's life between his childhood and the beginning of his ministry, a period not described in the New Testament) of his life. and he learned Buddhism and Hinduism. although some say Jesus didn't die when the crucifixion happened and his disciples took his half body to yogis to bring back to life. and he lived in Tibet until his death.

And Some Famous [Books](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0143028294), [Documentaries](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z-TOu_AITSI) are also made on this. Unlike British and Japanese theories, the Indian one gives some kind of "evidence" like the [tomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roza_Bal) claims to be Jesus's, some ancient scrolls say a person like Jesus. More information can be found on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unknown_years_of_Jesus)

How do respond to these claims?

Comment: There is zero, and I mean zero scholarly evidence for this. Actually there isn’t any evidence. The only real historical data we have are the gospels, and they very clearly state Christ died on a cross. Essentially every scholar, outside of some Muslims and Jesus Mythologists hold to this view. So mere assertion isn’t enough. I can just as easily claim that Jesus learned to ride a pony and tamed a unicorn before beginning his ministry. The amount of evidence between my claim and the India claim is the same, it’s just an assertion.

Comment: Also I’d hardly call a random book on Amazon with 200 some reviews "famous” and a YouTube video with a little over 150k views “famous”. It’s just ridiculous fantasy with no historical precedent.

Comment: @LukeHill I just linked the documentary which claims to be by BBC. But there are some [videos](https://youtu.be/TEvomvO8cb0) with over one million views.

Comment: Read my comment prior to my claim about the links to see why even a million isn’t relevant in the first place.

Comment: The original question was "Did Jesus Visit India?" Here the question is "how to respond to the claim." I gave a short answer in the original thread just now. To summarize:, we should respond to it as an invitation to dialog. One's faith should not be challenged by the possibility, and it seems like a perfect teaching moment.